# how to upgrade c++ COM components to cloud deployment

Tags: c++, windows, azure, com, cloud

We have set of C++ COM components which is running in windows 2008 server.

1.Inputs & outputs to C++-COM-components is via tcp sockets.
2.Processing will happen in multi threaded way.
3.Its core TCP socket server application build using IOCP for communication.

We would like to upgrade the traditional C++-com-components to cloud ready.

Cloud option-1: Windows Azure.--Since the most of the components are build using windows so preferred to use windows Azure.
1.Is it possible to convert existing c++-com-components to an web app that can be scalable & fault tolerant.

We like to minimally rewrite certain portions without the rewriting the whole component.

The questions are in high level, but asking is there any one done this already or would some of your experiences. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Windows Server 2008 is retired in Azure - so you will need to assess if the option with the VM with not supported OS is viable for you, or assess the opportunity to test it in 2008+ (starting from R2).

2) For being able to *minimally* (or event without) rewriting your software i see the only viable option is to host it on the VM. [I would try to migrate it by making the image from your server. You can deploy it to Hyper-V as a first convenient step.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/)

3) If you want to host it in Azure PaaS services, i believe it would be very hard to avoid rewriting simply because of the PaaS nature and lack of some components that can be preinstalled on the local versions.

Comment: Point 3 is totally unclear. What exactly in the "PaaS" nature would prevent such installation from working? Is it the LB in front of the role instances or is it anything else?